# What is the projection of my raster?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, geotools, epsg

Continuing what is written in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278350/obtaining-longitude-and-latitude-from-geotiff-with-geotools/278379), I show gdalinfo output

```
Size is 1200, 1400
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",42],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",12.5],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-598884.437500000000000,650790.250000000000000)
Pixel Size = (996.479919433593750,-999.677795410156250)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2018:04:01 00:10:06
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=/datamet/data/tmp/export/RADAR/36/RRN/VMI/VMI.geotif
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IDL TIFF file
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IDL 8.3, Exelis Visual Information Solutions, Inc.
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -598884.438,  650790.250) (  4d32'13.20"E, 47d34'44.14"N)
Lower Left  ( -598884.438, -748758.664) (  5d56'18.16"E, 35d 4'36.70"N)
Upper Right (  596891.466,  650790.250) ( 20d26'12.34"E, 47d34'50.73"N)
Lower Right (  596891.466, -748758.664) ( 19d 2'23.69"E, 35d 4'40.94"N)
Center      (    -996.486,  -48984.207) ( 12d29'17.00"E, 41d33'32.31"N)
Band 1 Block=1200x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

When I open it using GeoTools I get the following CRS:

```
PROJCS["unnamed", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 12.5], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 42.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", �], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]
```

I made an attempt and I get it

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42 +lon_0=12.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" source.tif target.tif 

ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds. 
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,1200,1400, skipping. 
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your raster is defined with an unusual transverse mercator projection using a classic WGS84 geoid (to be quick, shape of earth). As universal transverse mercator (UTM) are defined using equator as latitude of origin and equally distributed meridians along equator, your's is using 42° north as latitude of origin and 12.5° east as meridian so coordinates are somewhat centered on those coordinates. You can imagine an horizontal cylinder touching earth along 12.5° meridian and having 0 at the 42° north instead of equator

[edit] As per your question, you could project back (as a misuse of language, better unproject) your raster to lat/lon using gdalwarp command

> gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42 +lon_0=12.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" your_raster result.tif

- -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42 +lon_0=12.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" is your projection using proj4 syntax (what is displayed with gdalinfo is OGC/WKT)
- -t_srs "epsg:4326" stands for lat/lon:wgs84 (what you want)

Comment: how do I get latitude and longitude for every single point starting from these mercator coordinates?

Comment: your raster coordinates are projected that means they are on a flat surface instead of being on a spherical surface. latitude/longitude as you request are for sphere so your raster should be "unprojected" to return to spherical coordinates (lat/lon).

Comment: edited my answer with project to lat/lon

Comment: here is the output of the gdalwarp command:

ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,1200,1400, skipping.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Comment: I built a raster very similar to yours that displays the same information through gdalinfo and applied gdal_warp command as above and got a result raster without any errors and displaying good informations with gdalinfo. Please double check your parameters or is it your gdal version (mine is 2.2.3) or the weird character in scale_factor

Comment: try adding -s_srs="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42 +lon_0=12.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" along other parameters to force input spatial reference

Comment: This is my command  (gdal_warp not found, I used gdalwarp, but I think it's the same thing):

gdalwarp -s_srs='+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42 +lon_0=12.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' C:\Users\a.frabotta\Desktop\ProtCiv\VMI\01-04-2018-00-00.tif C:\Users\a.frabotta\pippo.tif

but I obtain  ERROR 6 unknown option name ...

My GDAL library version is 2.2.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75624/discussion-between-billy34-and-alessio-frabotta).

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.